# Create textplot on another page after ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is a sample of my code:

```
pdf("foo.pdf")
    toplot=data.frame(Vals, Factor, Group)
    ggplot(toplot, aes(x=Factor, y=Vals, fill=Group)) +
        geom_violin() +
        scale_x_discrete() +
        scale_y_continuous() +
        scale_fill_discrete() +
        theme_bw()

    textplot(c(
            paste0(info[1]," ", floor(-1*log10(wilcox.test(quant1_a, quant1_b)$p.value))), 
            paste0(info[2]," ", floor(-1*log10(wilcox.test(quant2_a, quant2_b)$p.value))), 
            paste0(info[3]," ", floor(-1*log10(wilcox.test(quant1_a, quant2_a)$p.value))), 
            paste0(info[4]," ", floor(-1*log10(wilcox.test(quant1_b, quant2_b)$p.value)))
    ), halign="left")
dev.off()
```

Basically, I'd like to plot violins for some biological data (2 conditions, 2 groups of genes so 4 violins), with the relevant p values after. However, the `textplot()` seems to plot over the `ggplot()`, completely erasing the violins. If I do `textplot()` then `ggplot()`, both will be plotted but it's not very reader-friendly. I know I could modify `par()` to plot twice on the same page, but I would rather keep them on two different pages.

Any idea why this is happening and how to stop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just put the text into a second blank ggplot using a custom `grob`.

I have had to create some dummy data to do this:

```
info   <- c("info 1", "info 2", "info 3", "info 4")

toplot <- data.frame(Vals = rnorm(1000), 
                     Factor = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 250), 
                     Group = rep(1:4, length =250))

page2  <- paste0(info[1]," -log of p = ", 
                 floor(-1*log10(wilcox.test(rnorm(10, 5), rnorm(10, 6))$p.value)), "\n", 
                 info[2]," -log of p = ", 
                 floor(-1*log10(wilcox.test(rnorm(10, 5), rnorm(10, 7))$p.value)), "\n", 
                 info[3]," -log of p = ", 
                 floor(-1*log10(wilcox.test(rnorm(10, 5), rnorm(10, 8))$p.value)), "\n", 
                 info[4]," -log of p = ", 
                 floor(-1*log10(wilcox.test(rnorm(10, 5), rnorm(10, 9))$p.value)))
```

The code itself is quite straightforward:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)


pdf("foo.pdf")

  ggplot(toplot, aes(x=Factor, y=Vals, fill=Group)) +
    geom_violin() +
    scale_x_discrete() +
    scale_y_continuous() +
    scale_fill_discrete() +
    theme_bw()

  ggplot() + 
    theme_void() + 
    annotation_custom(textGrob(page2))

dev.off()
```

The result looks like this:

foo.pdf page 1:

[image]

foo.pdf page 2:

[image]